# Modify Text property of an Entry while user is typing similar to PreviewKeyDown from wpf

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, events, xamarin.forms

I am looking to conditionally filter/alter the `Text` property of an `Entry` while user is typing. The same way [`PreviewKeyDown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.previewkeydown?view=netframework-4.7.2) event does in wpf: fired before the `KeyDown` event, which gives control to modify the user's input before being displayed to user while the later is typing.

Unfortunately in Xamarin such event does not exist. Below is a sample (put everything in code-behind only for sample) of what I have tried so far, but caused a stack overflow (bouncing between `Entry_TextChanged` event and `notifypropertychanged` in setter).

My question is not to correct my code, but a clean way to achieve the described requirement on top.

PS:
Doing the conditional modification on the setter is not an option as it is not a good design, and won't be reusable.

---

MyPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AppTest"
             x:Class="AppTest.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Entry Text="{Binding entrystr}"
               Keyboard="Numeric"
               TextChanged="Entry_TextChanged"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

MyPage.xaml.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace AppTest
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string _EntryStr;
        public string EntryStr
        {
            get { return _EntryStr; }
            set
            {
                if(Equals(_EntryStr, value))
                {
                    _EntryStr = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null) =>
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this;
        }

        private void Entry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            float OldValueFloat, NewValueFloat;
            float.TryParse(e.OldTextValue, out OldValueFloat);
            float.TryParse(e.NewTextValue, out NewValueFloat);

            ((sender as Entry).BindingContext as MainPage).EntryStr = NewValueFloat > 5 ?
                OldValueFloat.ToString() : NewValueFloat.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no such a lifecycle event of Entry in Xamarin .In your case handle the logic in Setter seems the best (or the only) way .

Comment: Is using custom renderers a viable option for you? Personally im intercepting input in them, then passing to forms, processing there with any custom filter i wish, then passing back to renderers.

Comment: You are free to answer, I am not quite familiar with custom renders, and also it may be helpful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really like the design by making it in the setter but it seems there is not a lot of options, I tried to make it more flexible/reusable.

---

ViewModelBase.cs

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T value, Func<T, T, T> PrefilterMethod = null, [CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        if (!Equals(field, value))
        {
            if (PrefilterMethod != null)
                field = PrefilterMethod.Invoke(field, value);
            else
                field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(name);
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
}
```

MainPageViewModel.cs

```
public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _EntryStr;
    public string EntryStr
    {
        get => _EntryStr;
        set => SetProperty(ref _EntryStr, value, Setter_Filter);
    }

private string Setter_Filter(string oldstr, string newstr)
{
    float OldValueFloat, NewValueFloat;
    float.TryParse(oldstr, out OldValueFloat);
    float.TryParse(newstr, out NewValueFloat);

    return  NewValueFloat > 5 ?
            OldValueFloat.ToString() : NewValueFloat.ToString();
}
```

MainPage.cs

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel();
}
```

Of course `TextChanged` event is no longer required.