# Xamarin Mask Entry Currency 2 Decimal Places

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, ivalueconverter

I'm using the following code to mask an entry field for currency. The only issue is I want to limit the input to 2 decimal places. How can I modify the code the accomplish this?

```cs
public class CurrencyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Decimal.Parse(value.ToString()).ToString("C");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string valueFromString = Regex.Replace(value.ToString(), @"\D", "");

        if (valueFromString.Length <= 0)
            return 0m;

        long valueLong;
        if (!long.TryParse(valueFromString, out valueLong))
            return 0m;

        if (valueLong <= 0)
            return 0m;

        return valueLong / 100m;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to prevent the user from entering more than 2 decimal places, or do you just want to round/truncate whatever they enter?

Comment: I want to prevent them from entering more than 2 decimal places

Comment: not sure if this will work, but the first thing I'd try is rounding the result to 2 decimals

Comment: @christinapapaaa11 take a look to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63960401/5228202)  may be it will be helpful in your case.

Comment: Could it work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to limit two decimals，you could add the conditions in the entry textchanged event.

like:

```
<Entry x:Name="entry" Keyboard="Numeric"  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" WidthRequest="600" TextChanged="Entry_TextChanged"></Entry>
```

in the behind code:

```
private void Entry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      
        if (e.NewTextValue.Contains("."))
        {
            if (e.NewTextValue.Length - 1 - e.NewTextValue.IndexOf(".") > 2)
            {
              var  s = e.NewTextValue.Substring(0, e.NewTextValue.IndexOf(".") + 2 + 1);
                entry.Text =s;
                entry.SelectionLength = s.Length;
            }
        }

    }
```

the effect:

[image]

Comment: how would you allow only 2 numbers "before" the decimal point - with this current logic implemented?